# Brackets around Stored Procedure in ADODB Command Text

Tags: sql-server, vba, vb6, adodb

Help me understand why this is happening!

I use the ADODB.Command object.  The Command Text is set to the Stored Procedure Name.

Sometimes, if I DON'T add brackets around the stored procedure name, I get a Syntax Error or Access Violation error.

Sometimes, if I DO add brackets around the stored procedure name, I get a Syntax Error or Access Violation error.

Code:

```
Dim objCmd As New ADODB.Command 
With objCmd
    .ActiveConnection = DBConnect() 
    .CommandText = "MyInsert" 
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc 
    .Parameters.Append 
    .CreateParameter("@MyId", adVarChar, adParamInput, 25, "123ABC") 
    .Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
End With
Set objCmd = Nothing
```

Comment: Dim objCmd As New ADODB.Command
    
    With objCmd
      .ActiveConnection = DBConnect()
      .CommandText = "MyInsert"
      .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
      .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@MyId", adVarChar, adParamInput, 25, "123ABC")
      .Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
    End With
       
    Set objCmd = Nothing

Comment: Please post samples of what doesn't work, along with some that do work.

Comment: (Your comment appeared right when I added my comment. Such timing!)

Comment: It's the same ones.  Sometimes they work, sometimes they don't.  All use the exact structure above.

Comment: If someone wouldn't mind formatting that for me, I'd appreciate it.  I can't get it to work.

Comment: I take it the line where you are adding the parameters is meant to be all on one line? If not that would cause your problem but I suspect it is just the way the code has been formatted. Can you confirm and also give the exact wording of the error message

Comment: Could you clarify is this a problem where it sometimes works and sometimes doesn't for the SAME procedure or is it a case where including brackets works for some procedures and not for others?

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some code? The only time I've run into that error with ADO and VB6 is when passing a Guid argument as a string (rather than bound to a parameter) and when the string includes the {} around the Guid.